# image width overridden by something else

Tags: html, jekyll-theme

Recently I moved my personal website to github.io and used jekyll's indigo theme. In one of my markdown page called about.md, I have the following tag.

```
<img src="../figs/foo.jpg" width="100%">
```

But this is overridden by another block.

```
.about img {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
 }
```

Because of which, the image I want to show for 100% is only displayed half of the page.

How will I override the .about img to show my image for 100%

Answer (score 1):

You can use the style attribute with **!important** to set the image width as below :-

`<img src="../figs/foo.jpg" style="width:100% !important;">`

With this you should also look the width of the parent tag of this  tag container

Answer (score 0):

Your current inline image width uses the width **attribute**. To overwrite the CSS you should use **more specific CSS**. Replace the attribute by CSS/style, like this:

```
<img src="../figs/foo.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
```

If you use the above, your inline CSS will win the specificity battle from the `.about img` selector.

For an easy to remember image about the specificity rules, look at [Speci-FISH-ity](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css-specificity/).